# include button id from one jsp to another jsp struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have two jsp pages using struts mainPage.jsp and subPage.jsp. I want to include subPage.jsp inside mainPage.jsp and get the id/name of the button of subPage.jsp in javascript function of `mainPage.jsp`. How to do it?

Comment: Exactly with what you are having problems?

Comment: Include second jsp as <%@include file="subPage.jsp" %> in first jsp. Then it will be consider as a single page for javascript. You can proceed as usual.

Answer (score 2):

In your `mainPage.jsp` you can include `subPage.jsp` as follows

```
<%@include file="subPage.jsp" %>
```

It will be rendered as a single HTML page, you can access any DOM elements of both the pages from javascript